# Find and change the value of first element in list that meets a requirement, do something else if not found

Tags: c#, performance, linq

This seems to be ridiculously easy, but I just can't seem to find a way to do it. Basically the title, I want to find the first item in my list that meets a requirement, and modify the value of that found item, and if none of the items in that list meets it, then do something else.

I was using a foreach loop to this, but it is definitely not the fastest way.

```
foreach (CustomClass foo in bar)
{
    if (!foo.Value)
    {
         foo.Value = true;
         currentCount++;
         break;
    }
}
```

I then tried to use `List.First()` and catching the exception when it can't find the value, but that is far slower, and I'm looking for performance.

**EDIT: Never mind about what is below**, I found how to make first or default work, but is there a faster way to do this multiple times than the foreach method? Thanks

---

So I tried FirstOrDefault, but I keep getting null reference exception

```
if (bar.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == false).Equals(null))
{
    break;
}
else
{
    thePicture.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == false).Value = true;
    currentCount++;
}
```

Anyone know how to make the first or default work? Or is there any other way to do this faster than the foreach method. *(This will be ran in another loop a lot of times)* Thanks!

Comment: LINQ will not be faster than a foreach. Both will iterate the same collection until they find the first element.

Comment: _I was using a foreach loop to this, but it is definitely not the fastest way._ It probably is.  Maybe a direct for-loop is a tad faster.. LINQ usually is not faster, just nice to write and better at sorting..

Comment: Though it depends on lots of factor primarily amount of data to process to understand the applicability of O(n) linear processing, within certain limits I have not really seen the Jaw dropping difference between Linq and foreach. Nonetheless, for such a scenario prescribed is to use foreach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` will return a null reference if no element is found - assuming the element type is a reference type. Instead of calling `Equals` on the result, just use `==`... and don't call it twice:

```
var first = bar.FirstOrDefault(c => !c.Value);
if (first == null)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    // Use first, I suspect.
    // (You don't in the sample code, but...)
}
```

Note that this won't be *faster* than an appropriate `foreach` loop, but it can be more readable.

Comment: Sort of new to C#, so sorry in advance if this question is obvious, but is `first` a shallow copy of the item in bar, so when I change first, will still change the item in bar?

Comment: @HandofC'thuhlu: Assuming your list is a list of classes, it's a reference. If you're unsure about how references work, you should learn more about that right now - it's *crucial* to working effectively with C#. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html

Answer (score -1):

```
(bar!=null)?((bar[1].value == true)?(do something):(do something)):do something)
```

Here you are only checking the first element in list right?
So why going for a loop.

Comment: Incorrect, first element that meet a condition, not just the first element. You need the func as shown in the other answer

Comment: Yeah, basically what @MrinalKamboj said, I'm looking for the first item that will meet a condition....